# Scala 2.10: Convert mutable Map of ListBuffer to readonly datastructure

Tags: scala-collections, listbuffer

I am using the following code to traverse directories and adding files to a `mutable Map` of `mutable ListBuffer`. The key is the directory name and the values are the list of files under that directory.

```
    def WalkDir(path:String): scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]] = {

      def collectFiles(p:Path, allFiles: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]]):  = {

           val fileIterator = ... //List all the files
           while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
                val f = fileIterator.next()

                if (f is not directory) { // pseduo code
                    val dir = f.getDir() // pseudo code
                    if (! allFiles.contains(f.getDir().toString()) 
                      {
                        val files = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
                        files += (f.path().toString()) // psudeo-code file path
                        allFiles.put(dir.toString(), files)
                     }
                    else {
                           val t_list = allFiles.get(dir.toString()
                            allFiles.put(dir.toString(), t_list += f.path().toString())
                    }
             }
              if (f is directory) collectFiles(f.getPath(), allFiles)

       }

          collectFiles(path, new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]])
   }
```

How to I convert the return value to `Map[String, List[String]]`? Is there a more 'functional' way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

The `java.nio.file` package has both `SimpleFileVisitor` and `Files` that should make this a lot easier. Subclass `SimpleFileVisitor`, overriding `preVisitDirectory` and `visitFile`; then drive it with `Files.walkFileTree`.

But the more general answer to your question is that this is a *fold* operation, so using your existing code it would look something like:

```
filesIterator.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]]) { case (map, file) =>
  ...
  // return an updated map
  map + (dir -> updatedVector)
}
```

I'd also use a `Vector` instead of a `List`, since lists are O(n) to insert each element at the end.

Comment: @Neel Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks !